# How do I check using whether a db record is present using rawQuery?

Tags: android, database

Hi I'm new to databases in android and I have an app that draws rectangles and circles on a canvas.There's a delete button to delete the shape that I've drawn.In my ShapesDbHelper.java I have a method called deleteShape that has to check whether the db record is present before deleting it.

```
public boolean deleteShape(int shapeID) {
    boolean result = false; //did the delete succeed or not

    //check if db record is present
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + SchemeShapes.Shape.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE SchemeShapes.Shape.ID = ?",new String[]{String.valueOf(shapeID)} );
    int delete =0

    if (mCursor!=null) {
         delete = db.delete(SchemeShapes.Shape.TABLE_NAME, SchemeShapes.Shape.ID + "= ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(shapeID)});

    }
    if (delete!=0){
        result=true;
    }

   mCursor.close();
    db.close();
    return result;
}
```

However, the delete button only works when I delete directly without using rawQuery to check db existence. So there must be something wrong with my rawQuery input params.I've read the documentation but I don't really understand it.

This my createTable method.Any help will be appreciated.

```
private final static String SHAPES_TABLE_CREATE =
            "CREATE TABLE " +
                    SchemeShapes.Shape.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    SchemeShapes.Shape.ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, " +
                    SchemeShapes.Shape.SHAPE_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                    SchemeShapes.Shape.SHAPE_TYPE + " TEXT," +
                    SchemeShapes.Shape.SHAPE_X + " INTEGER," +
                    SchemeShapes.Shape.SHAPE_Y + " INTEGER," +
                    SchemeShapes.Shape.SHAPE_WIDTH + " INTEGER," +
                    SchemeShapes.Shape.SHAPE_HEIGHT + " INTEGER," +
                    SchemeShapes.Shape.SHAPE_RADIUS + " INTEGER," +
                    SchemeShapes.Shape.SHAPE_BORDER_THICKNESS + " INTEGER," +
                    SchemeShapes.Shape.SHAPE_COLOR + " TEXT);";
```

Answer (score 0):

Also check if `(mCursor.getCount() >0)` before deleting.

```
if (mCursor!=null && mCursor.getCount() > 0) {
         delete = db.delete(SchemeShapes.Shape.TABLE_NAME, SchemeShapes.Shape.ID + "= ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(shapeID)});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
if (mCursor!=null) {
         delete = db.delete(SchemeShapes.Shape.TABLE_NAME, SchemeShapes.Shape.ID + "= ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(shapeID)});

}
```

should be:

```
if (mCursor!=null && mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
             delete = db.delete(SchemeShapes.Shape.TABLE_NAME, SchemeShapes.Shape.ID + "= ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(shapeID)});

}
```

Comment: I already tried if mCursor!=null mCursor.moveToFirst() before deleting but the app still crashes after I press my delete button.

Comment: Please post your crash log

Answer (score 0):

```
I hope this will work for you.
//For Check id is present or not
public boolean CheckRecordInDBorNot(String id) {
String Query = "Select * from SchemeShapes.Shape.TABLE_NAME where SchemeShapes.Shape.ID='" + id + "'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
        cursor.close();
        return false;
    }
    cursor.close();
    return true;
}

//for Delete
public void deleteShape(String id){
long l= db.delete("SchemeShapes.Shape.TABLE_NAME", " SchemeShapes.Shape.ID"+ " = ?", new String[]{id});
Log.e("count",""+l);
}

//paste these method and check this way.

if(CheckRecordInDBorNot(your id)){
deleteShape(your id);
}else{
  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Record Not Present...",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```